# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el print de mi función aparezca en el scrolledtext al presionar el botón?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, entrada, scrollbar

Quiero hacer que al presionar el botón mi `print` del código aparezca en el cuadro de texto o `scrolledtext`. ¿De qué otra forma puedo hacerlo?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

#Creacion de mi funcion
def resultado():
    print("En matemáticas y álgebra lineal, un sistema de ecuaciones lineales")

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('NAES Solver')
window.geometry('300x300')

src = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width = 20, height = 5, wrap = tk.WORD)
src.grid(column = 7, row = 7)

#Creacion del boton
action=ttk.Button(window, text="Picale", command=resultado).grid(column=0, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Chepe, lo que puedes hacer es cambiar el `print` de tu función **resultado**, y usar `src.insert(tk.INSERT, "Un texto")`. Con esto consigues **insertar** el texto que quieres, en el `scrolledtext`.

El código queda casi igual:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

#Creacion de mi funcion
def resultado():
    src.insert(tk.INSERT, "En matemáticas y álgebra lineal, un sistema de ecuaciones lineales")

window = tk.Tk()

window.title('NAES Solver')
window.geometry('300x300')

src = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width = 20, height = 5, wrap = tk.WORD)
src.grid(column = 7, row = 7)

#Creacion del boton
action=ttk.Button(window, text="Picale", command=resultado).grid(column=0, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por su apoyo, le agradezco demasiado, buen dia. :)